# access property of a data class dynamically like Obj[propertyName]

Tags: kotlin

I am learning Kotlin (coming from JS/TS background) and wondering if it is possible to access properties of a data class dynamically. For e.g.

```
data class Obj (private val name: String){}

val obj = Obj(name="sel")
```

would it be possible to do now:

```
  val getValueOfField = "name"
  println(obj[getValueOfField])
```

When I tried, it failed but also noticed type inference is an issue. When I did:

```
 Obj::class.declaredMemberProperties.contains(getValueOfField)
```

to check if the field exists, it still failed to compile due to data inference issue.

Comment: The term for doing this is “reflection”. You almost never should need to do this in a strongly typed language though. It’s mostly used by libraries that do serialization.

Comment: It's only natural, when learning a new language, to reach for the patterns and techniques you're already familiar with — but statically-typed languages have a different mindset, and some of those idioms don't translate very well. So while it may be possible to do what you're asking (using reflection), the result is likely to be slow, long-winded, hard to read, fragile, insecure, and hard to debug and maintain. (cont)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's the bigger problem you're trying to solve? Because there are almost certainly different approaches, which work _with_ the type system instead of trying to defeat it, that would be much better in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No dynamic access is available without using reflection as the return type of such an operation would be unknown and so type safety would be lost.

You can do [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html) though which is almost as flexible:

```
data class Name (
    val firstName: String,
    val secondName: String
){}


fun main() {
    val (name, _) = Name("Nie", "Selam")
    println("$name is learning Kotlin") // prints Nie is learning Kotlin
}
```

See [Kotlin playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS43LjIxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZGF0YSBjbGFzcyBOYW1lIChcbiAgICB2YWwgZmlyc3ROYW1lOiBTdHJpbmcsXG4gICAgdmFsIHNlY29uZE5hbWU6IFN0cmluZ1xuKXt9XG5cblxuZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gXHR2YWwgKG5hbWUsIF8pID0gTmFtZShcIk5pZVwiLCBcIlNlbGFtXCIpXG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihcIiRuYW1lIGlzIGxlYXJuaW5nIEtvdGxpblwiKVxufSJ9).